# Did React-native support building with Experimental Plugin?

Tags: android, android-ndk, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using gradle-experimental:0.7.2 to build my react-native project since it support NDK.
But I got this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/username/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/react.gradle' line: 25

* What went wrong:
Could not find property 'android' on project ':app'.
```

And here are my `build.gradle`

#### Project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

#### (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: "com.android.model.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.awesomeproject"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 16
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 22
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            }
        }
        splits {
            abi {
                reset()
                enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
                universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
                include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            }
        }
        ndk {
            moduleName "elian-wrapper-jni"
            ldLibs.add("log")
            stl "stlport_static"
        }
        sources {
            main {
                jni {
                    dependencies {
                        library "elian" linkage "shared"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
                // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
                def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
                def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
                if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                    output.versionCodeOverride =
                            versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
                }
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {

            elian {
                headers.srcDir "src/main/jni"
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file("src/main/jniLibs/${targetPlatform.getName()}/libelian.a")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

I'm wondering does react-native support building with gradle expiremental plugin, or there are some mistake of my gradle setting?

Many many thanks!